# Six monitor support

Tags: display, graphics, multiple-monitors

I have a new custom built computer with the following graphics cards in it:

- XFX Double D HD-687A-ZDFC
- Radeon HD 6870 1GB 256-bit GDDR5 PCI Express 2.1 x16 HDCP Ready CrossFireX Support Video Card with Eyefinity

I would like to know if I would be able to run 4 40" tvs and 2 24' monitors if I ran two of these cards in crossfire mode.

Comment: Do you mean 24 inch monitors, or 24 _foot_ monitors (as you typed)?

Answer (score 2):

The [XFX Double D HD-687A-ZDFC](http://xfxforce.com/en-gb/Products/Graphics-Cards/ATI/AMD-Radeon-HD-6000/AMD-Radeon-HD-6870/HD-687A-ZDFC.aspx) has 5 outputs (2x DVI, 2x miniDisplayport, 1x HDMI) which can be used to support up to 4 displays.

[image: XFX-AMD_HD-687A-ZDBC image from xfxforce site]

To run 6 displays you would need two of these cards.

You will have to run them as normal cards, **not in Crossfire mode**. (If you use crossfire then only the outputs on the main card will be used. The second card is used as a calculation unit and it will not output any signal).

Which already answers your question:

> I would like to know if I would be able to run 4 40" tvs and 2 24' monitors if I ran two of these cards in crossfire mode.

No, you would six outputs on a single card to use CrossFire mode.

E.g. a newer version of [this card](http://www.amd.com/us/products/desktop/graphicsati-radeon-hd-5000/hd-5870-eyefinity-6-edition/pages/overview.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

These cards will run three independent displays each *if* the third output (and beyond if it's a four-to-six port variant) is actually DisplayPort.  If your displays don't support DisplayPort you'll need to use an *active*, not passive, adapter.

(Crossfire is totally irrelevant here - the cards should Just Work when you install them, no Crossfire necessary.  I actually think it might disable outputs, it's honestly been long enough since I tried that I forget.   I'm assuming you're talking about a modern OS - note that there is not driver support for this under Windows XP in any capacity).

EDIT: It looks like this XFX SKU is a bit of a nonstandard one, but I suspect the limitations are the same.  This answer should be good for most near-reference Radeons released in the last few years as well.

Comment: Why an active adapter? I've used a passive displayport to DVI converter before in a triple monitor setup and it's worked fine.

Comment: @nhinkle - Existing Radeon cards specifically tend to have at least three outputs, but only two TMDS clocks, so they can't natively push three DVI or HDMI signals - that's why *active* conversion to DisplayPort.  This should be covered on quite a few other questions.  (There are a few SKUs that do some trickery to get around this, like dropping dual-link support on one output to support a third passively on some Sapphire 6770 and 7770s, or requiring identical EDID timing data across the monitors like the FirePro 2460, but this is not that common.)

Comment: Interesting. I'm driving one monitor at WQHD on dual-link DVI, another at 1080p on regular DVI, and a third at 1680x1050 on a passive DP->DVI converter.